# Apple Help Authoring

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm following [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-CIHEAADH) to public some Apple help. The application I work on has had help built in for years, but it stopped working all of a sudden, and no changes were made to the application plist or any of the help files. We're presuming Apple changed something, so I made sure it met the specifications Apple were requiring. When I say "not working" I mean that our links using `NSHelpManager` will open the help viewer but bring back a page not found.

Things to check off the list:

1. There is an anchor with the correct name at the top of the page
2. The folder structure is a replica of what is in that article linked earlier
3. We are re-indexing the help pages
4. We do clear out all of the caches

Here's the code we use to open the help page:

```
NSString *locBookName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleHelpBookName"];
[[NSHelpManager sharedHelpManager] openHelpAnchor:@"mypage" inBook:locBookName];
```

In this instance we'd have a page with a `<a name="mypage"></a>` at the top so it should link correctly. Our scripts are as follows:

hvfix (clears all caches):

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.help*
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.help*
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
killall helpd
defaults write com.apple.helpindexer IndexAnchors YES
```

updatehelpindex.sh (re-generates indexes)

```
#!/bin/sh
hiutil -C -f MyApp.help/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/MyApp.helpindex
MyApp.help/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/
```

We do a build, drop the folder into the Applications folder in order to register the application + the help. We even try a restart or logoff/logon and still we get nothing. I know it's a very fiddly process but nothing we try seems to work. All we want to be able to do is use the `NSHelpManager` to open a help anchor. Undoubtedly this works in 10.6+ as so many other apps do it (some reports suggest it won't work in 10.7/8, but they must be untrue).

Ideas?

**EDIT (folder structure):**

This is within the MyProj.help folder that's in a sub-directory of the overall Cocoa project called 'help'.

```
+ Contents
     Info.plist
     + Resources
         + shrd
              (a bunch of image files)
         + English.lproj
               MyProj.helpindex
               index.html
               + css
               + pgs
               + gfx
```

And in the folders are precisely what's as expected, 'css' has a bunch of CSS files in it, 'pgs' has the HTML pages and 'gfx' has image files.

Comment: Have you tried putting the MyApp.help file at the top of the Resources directory?   I seem to remember that there was a move sometime in the last few releases to repackage that so that it was not within an individual language folder as your script indicates.

Comment: Ah yes, I had seen a few examples around whereby it was /Resources/MyApp.helpindex/English.lproj instead. I'll have a bash later

Comment: Ah sorry, it is at the top of the Resources directory, so that can't be it!

Comment: Can you add your basic directory structure (edited output from `ls -R`) and the contents of the Info.plist inside of the `MyApp.help/Contents` directory?

Comment: Just edited the main question to reflect the structure. ls -R yields a heck of a lot, so I just summarised it.

Comment: After 10 years did Apple finally fix it? Dont looks like because i still cant link to an anchor in MacOS 14 in 2024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this one's been quite a roller-coaster of confusion but it has something to do with with your folder structure setup in Xcode. Here's some things worth knowing:

- People opt to put it in English.lproj. Don't do this, for a few reasons. First it won't display the sub-directories/files in Xcode if you dragged the help folder into your file listing, and secondly stuff in that folder is supposed to be flat, not structured.
- Create a "help" folder in the root and put your files in that. You can then put them in a sub-directory called "English.lproj" if you want localisation.
- Don't create a ".help" folder which contains all of your help files. This seems to break indexing. We don't know why.
- Instead, have /help/Contents/stuff and drag and drop that folder into your project directory listing (mine's in "Resources" group). Make sure it's a blue folder and that you can see the entire directory (all of your HTML etc.)
- Run the help indexer against it to generate the .helpindex file
- Make sure your plist entries reflect the name of that folder and the meta tag name specified in your index.html file

If you follow the above rules things should work fine. It seems in ML that creating a .help folder breaks things from here on out, so basically, don't follow the Apple guide.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a bug in the way sandboxing affects the HelpViewer's directory search when a HelpBook is registered with the system (as outlined in [this bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/12116431)), which fully explains why it shows up on 10.7 and 10.8, but not 10.6 and earlier.  Even Apple's [NSAlertTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NSAlertTest/Introduction/Intro.html) suffers from it.  Unfortunately, as the bug report remains unsolved as of the time of this post, there is no viable solution, but what few tests I've run have confirmed that NSHelpManager flat-out ignores the sandboxed help plist on my machine.

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted this one. My answer should elaborate enough. I've tested it on 10.6 and it worked fine and added some hints based on what I learnt, but nevertheless your answer is important in this context for whoever may come across this question. There's quite a lot to take into consideration and I'm in the (long) process of writing a blog post to cover all aspects. I'll link to this SO Q/A. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Sounds good.  It's really unfortunate how some edge-case classes can languish under new OS updates.

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this response here because I found a very dumb way of fixing this. By using Apple's `hiutil` command line tool, I saw that all Apple's official help books use some sort of indexing using a redirector file:

```
$ hiutil -Df /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Xcode.help/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/search.helpindex
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
>     <key>dev01043b473</key>
>     <array>
>         <string>/redirect.html?topic=dev01043b473</string>
>     </array>
>     <key>dev0125622ec</key>
>     <array>
>         <string>/redirect.html?topic=dev0125622ec</string>
>     </array>
> ...
```

Inspired by this, I attempted to generate a `.searchindex` file manually using `NSUnarchiver` to open the file created by `hiutil`, changing it,  and using `NSArchiver` to write back to a file, but my anchors would still not work like I wanted.

I cloned TextEdit's help book based on Apple's undisclosed "Eagle" help engine (`/Library/Documentation/Resources/Eagle/index.html`), which produces the pretty help books all Apple apps use now. But because I was using HTML indexing, my anchors would lead to plain HTML files, which weren't prettified by Eagle.

[image: Noto help without style screenshot]

Then I struck this dumb idea: It's a lot of work, but if you create a separate html file for each anchor, you can use the meta redirect head tag just like in the `redirect.html`, except your redirects will be static. Therefore, for my `editor-prefs.html` file, I created a `editor-prefs-anchor.html` file with the following contents:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Editor Options</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/editor-prefs" />
</head>

<body>
    <a id="editor-prefs">
</body>

</html>
```

The meta redirect tag takes care of redirecting to the proper Eagle-powered URL, and it works!

[image: Noto Help screenshot]

If anyone was struggling with Eagle like me, I hope this helps you!

Comment: I think you're leading the way with Eagle. Thanks to stumbling upon your project, I'm aware that it exists. However, instead of separate `-anchor.html` files, just put the redirect in the non-anchor HTML file. When the main `index.html` file AJAX-loads the file, all of `head` is stripped out. Searching help still links to the content file, so you still end up with unstyled page. Putting the redirect into that page ensures that the main `index.html` loads it, instead.

Comment: Has this facility changed location, or been removed in Catalina? Thanks

Comment: @DavidDelMonte Yes, unfortunately Eagle is completely gone in Catalina, and Apple seems to be using 100% online help bundles, which is a disappointment to say the least.

Comment: This gave me hope to fix my anchor problem but it seems meta refresh is another non working thing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue (anchors not working in my app's help book) and did some poking around in the help books of other Apple apps, specifically Safari. I found this interesting entry in the Info.plist in the Safari.help bundle in the Safari app:

```
 <key>HPDBookIndexPath</key>
    <string>search.helpindex</string>
```

I changed this to match the name of the .helpindex file in my app's help bundle, and anchors started working.