# How to best author a Apple Helpbook for a macOS app?

Tags: macos

macOS apps, e.g. Photos.app, provide a help panel to the user [image]

[image]

Is there a way to author **such** a Help Book in your own macOS app?
Is there a way to at least provide a toolbar to be used for a table of contents?

I am asking specifically about the UI and all the user interactions. Not how to generally create and register a helpbook.

**Update**

Here is what I’ve been able to find/gather/learn from others. A Help Book appears to run on a separate app/process called “HelpViewer”. Any Apple macOS app displaying a help makes use of a DDMViewerController that isn’t public.

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is an “app.css” and an “app.js” being used by the Apple macOS app “index.html” of the Apple Help Book. The Javascript one manipulates the DOM to create the “show-hide” link that toggles the Sidebar. Haven’t been able to find how to instruct HelpViewer to use a sidebar.

There is a WWDC talk from back in 2014, “Introducing the Modern WebKit API” that talks about “User Scripts” and “Script Messages” which allow communication between a Webview and Cocoa. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/206/

AFAICS, there is no way to have HelpViewer display a custom view or have a sidebar. My *guess* is that you would have to implement everything yourself. That is an NSSplitViewController, NSToolbar, NSOutlineView, any Javascript alongside the “app.css” to get the look and feel.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39932819/2143236 ? It can open and load the sidebar, and then you use JS to insert your comment. Not posting as an answer, because I will test this myself.

Comment: You're way overthinking this. It's just HTML+JS.

Comment: @balthisar interested in understanding why you think I'm overthinking it. As far as I can understand, it's a combination of Cocoa (the side bar) and HTML, JS. Toggling the side bar is not enough since the NSOutlineView needs to be populated somehow.

Comment: The sidebar is just HTML, too! If you dissect any of Apple's help books, you'll see that they're just HTML. For example [iTunes Help](https://help.apple.com/itunes/mac/12.7/index.html?localePath=en.lproj) is the same on the web (where you can inspect it) and in the help book. If you provide the same navigation structure, the Apple Help Viewer will give you that navigation sidebar, too.

Comment: @balthisar based on my findings (look at the screenshot that shows debugging the UI Hierarchy for the Maps Help Book), the sidebar is not HTML.

Comment: I'll be more precise: it's _generated_ from HTML. Consider my [helpbook online](http://www.balthisar.com/manuals/Balthisar%20Tidy%20(web)/Contents/Resources/). Download that application, and look at its Help. It has the same sidebar as Apple's help, and even the same buggy TOC button in Help Viewer, because it *is* Apple's help, made from 100% HTML+JS.

Comment: "it's generated from HTML", agreed! I have tried to reverse engineer it but couldn't find the correct HTML that generates the sidebar. I will have a look at your application, thanks! Can you also add an answer to this post with more detailed steps? Appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should answer "with more detailed steps"; I'm using Apple's JS with some modifications to support srcset, which seemed like the simplest approach. Have a look at the WIP version of [Middlemac 3](https://github.com/middlemac/middlemac/tree/version300-dev), which is what I used to build that help book. I definitely don't want to provide an answer pointing to my own repo!

Comment: @balthisar I'm confused to be honest :) Is there an official tool provided by Apple to author a HelpBook like I mention on the question in this post? I am currently looking at Middlemac 3 but I'm even more at a loss. I guess, when I say "detailed steps" what I mean is, the minimum directory structure, HTML, JS involved to have an Apple HelpBook with a sidebar.

Comment: There's no official tool, but Apple provides its JS on every macOS installation from 10.10. It's undocumented, so you're better off linking to your own copy. Another project [jekyll-apple-help](https://github.com/chuckhoupt/jekyll-apple-help) also generates modern looking help books, including sidebar, without using Apple's JS, and the JS looks a lot simpler than's Apple's. But, really, it does the same thing as Apple's JS, and builds a menu in HTML. So the minimum directory structure is that for any help book, plus what what jekyll-apple-help offers if you prefer to avoid Apple's JS.

Comment: @balthisar ok let me ask a more specific question. Do you know what HTML, JS you need to have defined so that the sidebar appears and works with the toggle button? Can you provide this as an answer without the need to link to any tooling?

Comment: Check out the JS on this [sample](https://github.com/balthisar/sample_apple_help/blob/master/Middlemac_(free).help/Contents/Resources/index.html) HTML file. It enables the TOC button in Help Viewer, and the rest, as discussed, is simple HTML+JS. If you clone the whole project, the sample Xcode project will run that Help Book for you. It's not nearly as impressive as the projects mentioned above, but it is, as requested, stripped down to the most bare essentials.

Comment: @balthisar I just realised this. The sample you sent me and the Help Book in Balthisar are not creating the sidebar in the same way as the one used by Apple. At least not in High Sierra. The sidebar in the Maps Help book is behaving exactly like the one used by a NSSplitView. i.e. there is a handle to drag the sidebar open and resize it. Generally speaking, it does look pretty similar as well as maintaining the sidebar state if you navigate to another help book.

Comment: @balthisar wanted to add that Apple's Xcode Help Book appears to be using that "old" style navigation.

Comment: Hmmm... let me see if I can figure out what Maps.app is doing differently. I've just opened its Help, and I do see what you mean. When I "send to Safari," it's interesting that the TOC doesn't open a sidebar, but a popover. There may be some hidden `window.HelpViewer` JavaScript property that Apple's help is hooking into in HelpViewer (similar to their `showTOCButton` property). It seems that Script Editor.app has a similar sidebar, and I suppose other macOS default applications do, too. Hidden API's suck, and then the question becomes, do we use them anyway?

Comment: @balthisar another thing I noticed is that every macOS app that uses that style of help *does not* have a .help bundle in its application bundle. It also requires an internet connection (Try accessing it without being connected to the Internet). Another thing I noticed is that an HTTP request is made that returns a JSON which I guess is used to construct the help. e.g. https://gist.github.com/qnoid/60062e0894533e6d4d96104bd1c6af7c Re hidden API's. One thing is how Apple will respond to an app submitted to the App Store using that Help. So yeah ‍♂️

Comment: I've been wondering how this works myself. There's nothing in the application .plist that would indicate a URL for a help book; the app .plist looks just like everyone else's. Looking at the private headers for `HVWebDelegate`, there are some new functions, but I'm having trouble determining which ones are exposed to JS. For example, `setSidebarButtonEnabled:onExpand:onCollapse:` seems to work identically to the older  10.10 `setSidebarButtonEnabled:onCheck:onUncheck:`. There are other references to "contentSidebar" too, but I'm not getting anywhere with them.

Comment: Also in Console any time anytime the Help Viewer is started, it fails with a message that its looking for `nav[role=navigation]`, so maybe it's trying to autopopulate a sidebar automatically. I've not cracked that nut yet, either. I'd like to find a way to trap the HTTP requests. It's not something I've had to do before, but I'll look into that. How'd you capture that JSON response?

Comment: I have too come across these methods and even managed to enable/disable the sidebar button but no more than that. I believe the app.js used by those help books might provide an answer. AFAICU, any elements with custom attributes, like role, are autogenerated, as in, they shouldn’t be explicitly declared. Typically something else has gone bad earlier which lead to failing to autogenerate the correct HTML. For network trace you can use mitmproxy, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/04/11/tracing-all-network-machine-traffic-using-mitmproxy-for-mac-osx/

Comment: Another hiccup is it looks like this sidebar is available only for 10.13. When I boot up a 10.12 VM, it's the same, old "eagle" framework, and when I choose the option to view in Safari, it uses all of the older JS. So if we _do_ manage to crack this, you won't be able to provide help to pre-10.13 systems. Thanks for the mitm tip; what an _awesome_ tool.

Comment: @balthisar that does it then. Thank you for your perseverance, kind demeanour, professionalism and contributions. Your support has provided me with a better understanding. Have even managed to put together a Help book using the "old" format with a hacked css to make it look/behave like the one I was interested in. That is good enough for now. Thanks again.

Comment: Given that bounties aren't refundable, I'm tempted to post an answer saying that right now, it's a private API and can't currently be done. It's something I plan to pursue, though, as I'm a strong advocate for doing Help Books right!

Comment: @balthisar you should! Would be nice to have an answer that gives all the context. i.e. "private api", "old vs new way", "use css to get the style right".

Comment: Guys, have the discussion continued elsewhere? What's new with modern Apple Help format? Trying to reverse-engineer it right now and, gosh, it's hard. Currently I'm interested in dark mode support. Managed to add it to the Eagle clone but it fails to update dynamically due to some lines in app.js. Haven't found a way to bypass this.

Comment: @VitaliiVashchenko the short answer is that even though I did get it to work with the modern Apple Help Format, I didn't get around to writing a step by step guide on how to do it. I did reverse engineer it at the time and yes it was hard. The best thing I can offer is to check the Help Book for Windmill that I was able to create https://windmill.io/mac/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to implement the sidebar as shown in the Maps and other built-in macOS applications from 10.13 onward.

Versions of macOS from 10.10 (built-in applications) implement sidebar navigation with HTML and JavaScript, and Apple Help Viewer itself offers a `window.HelpViewer` object with some hooks that enable/disable the Help Viewer's table of contents button. Once enabled, it will callback into your own JavaScript where you can show/hide TOC via CSS or JS.

From approximately 10.10, Apple's non-built-in applications have also been using this technique. For example, iTunes and Xcode help both do this.

From 10.13, macOS has a newer version of Help Viewer that provides an actual Cocoa-native table of contents and windows splitter, as well as some new properties on `window.HelpViewer`; presumably these can be used to enable/disable the Cocoa sidebar and populate the TOC, but these are undocumented and I'm not sure anyone outside of Apple has been able to reverse-engineer this functionality yet.

And in any case, it wouldn't work if you offer Help Books to pre-10.13 users, and the use of undocumented API's restricts applications from the App Store (although, I'm not certain that Apple scans Help Book JavaScripts for API usage as part of their review).

(There are also a *lot* of other changes to how Apple's built-in application Help works now, too, but that's another topic entirely.)

Thus the answer for now is we can't, or shouldn't, or just don't know how. Alternatives include using something like using jekyll-apple-help (no affiliation) or Middlemac 3 (my project), or just rolling your own.

For those interested in knowing how Apple does it, I've documented a lot of it [here](http://www.balthisar.com/manuals/Middlemac3_(free)/Contents/Resources/#/topic-apple_help_books-dissect_modern_help) (disclosure: link to my own website).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether Apple's current applications still use it, but there is a *very old* API on macOS for **Help Books**. Apple has [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-CIHEAADH) on how to create them and some [introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/user_help_intro/user_assistance_intro.html). In short: Help books are standard HTML files with additional proprietary anchors. Those anchors are accessible via the class `NSHelpManager`, e.g. to open the help book at a specific page.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813958/apple-help-authoring).

Comment: The Apple documentation hasn't been updated since 2013-01-28. Have already taken a look and haven't found anything regarding the navigation sidebar. Based on some reverse engineering and tinkering it's more than a simple HTML. There is a javascript file that alters the DOM. There is CSS with very specific classes that hook into it. There is some sort of locale selection and redirection between pages. And so on and so forth.

Comment: I agree. I myself used Help Books the last time in the PowerPC era and would not recommend to not rely on them. However, I'm wondering why `NSHelpManager` is still there.

Comment: @mschmidt, `NSHelpManager` is still useful; it's what allows us to open an anchor directly, such as proving context-sensitive help, rather than end up on the landing page.